Removing a redundant join in CriteriaBuilder/CriteriaQuery when doing a count group by aggregation
I am doing a group-by-count aggregation with CriteriaQuery.
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Tuple.class);
Root<Device> root = query.from(Device.class);
query.groupBy(root.get("version"));
query.multiselect(root.get("version"), criteriaBuilder.count(root));

But it generates the following SQL
select
        d1_0.version,
        count(d1_0.id) 
    from
        device d1_0 
    join
        device_item ss1_0 
            on d1_0.id=ss1_0.device_id 
    where
        d1_0.hardware_version=? 
    group by
        1 
    fetch
        first ? rows only

Now this is not wrong the device class does have a one-to-many to deviceitem but I don't need it for this group by and it takes half the time if I remove it.
I tried distinct and I changed the "criteriaBuilder.count(root)" to "criteriaBuilder.count(root.get("id")" and made one-to-many fetch eager but it still keeps the join.
thanks
@Entity
@Table(name = "device")
@Data
@FieldNameConstants
public class Device {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    UUID id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "device", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<DeviceItem > items= new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "device_item ")
@Data
@FieldNameConstants
public class DeviceItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    UUID id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "device_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    Device device;
}


Ideally, it should not use the join; I have tested it. Can you please add your pom.xml and entity classes.
